# Problem with printf or scanf (wont print the number properly)

Tags: c

I am trying to read numbers from file, the function prints only the digits after the decimal point. any idea why this happens?
thanks!

```
float Read() {    
    int i, k, w, m, n, j;    
    float number;    
    float a[m];    

    FILE *fil1;    
    fil1 = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");    
    w = 0; k = 0;     
    while (fscanf(fil1, "%d", &n) != EOF) {    
        fscanf(fil1, "%f", &number);    
        a[k] = number;    
        printf("%d => %f \n", i, a[k]);    
        w++;k++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What data does the file contain, what output did you expect, and what output do you get?

Comment: m is garbage at the 4th line that reads: `float a[m];`

Comment: the numbers are 2.00 5.00 0.00 8.50 1.20 9.00 9.00 0.00, it prints 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.20 0.00 0.00 0.00

Comment: Why are you reading an integer `n` (which isn't in the file) and not even printing it?

Comment: As well as the comment made by @Youssef13, you need to realise that, for an input stream that has, say `123.456` in it, the `fscanf(fil1, "%d", &n)` call will read (and consume) the `123` part - leaving only `.456` for the subsequent `fscanf(file, "%f", &number);` line to read.

Comment: Why are you reading an integer n (which isn't in the file) and not even printing it? - it was supposed to be %f, and that was the problem, now it works!

Comment: Please don't post new informations as comments, they will be ignored. You can always [edit] your question, do you see this link on the left below your question? And, please, take the [tour] and read "[ask]".

Answer (score 0):

change n to be float
and read it as float:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

float Read()
{
    int k, w;
    float   n;
    float a[100];

    FILE* fil1;
    fil1 = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    w = 0; k = 0;
    while (fscanf(fil1, "%f", &n) != EOF) {
        a[k] = n;
        printf("%f \n", a[k]);
        w++; k++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That would skip every other number.

Answer (score 0):

You're scanning the file twice, you're basically skipping every second number. this should fix it.

```
float Read (){    
int i,k,w,m,n,j;    
float   number;    
float a[m];    

 FILE *fil1;    
fil1 = fopen("numbers.txt","r");    
 w=0; k = 0;     
  while (fscanf(fil1, "%f", &n) != EOF){    
a[k]=n;    
  printf ("%d => %f \n",i, a[k]);    
 w++;k++;}
```